# Electron Readline

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, electron

I'm trying to build an app using electron, it's designed to get a GUI later but for now i'm just trying to do this:

```
function test(){

  console.log("In Test")

  var readline = require('readline');
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

  rl.on('line', function(line){
    console.log(line);
  })

}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
app.on('ready', test);
```

On launching `npm start`, I see the "`In Test`" log, but when I type something in my shell, it's not returned to me as I need it to be by the Readline module.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: I just saw that it was actually a bug. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017963/electron-readline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Electron the console becomes the Chromium console which is not like the terminal you're used to. Readline is not going to work as far as I know. The blink console in Chromium does not support reading input this way. It operates more like a debug REPL where you can type JS code, inspect variables, etc. It's not for user input. I don't think you're going to be able to get input supplied from that console into `stdin`, which is where the readline module is waiting to see data.

---

## Update

I assumed OP was using the dev tools console expecting it to work like a shell. He was using it properly. The actual issue is [a bug](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5384) with node's readline module on Windows. Node devs are actively working to fix it. It's a regression bug that was fixed once before but appeared again in recent versions of node.

Comment: Your comment is very clear and I wasn't aware about that at all !

That's a very usefull thing to know. (And that's explains a lot..).

I eventually found a little trick: using `readSync` in a loop.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: What command could I type to see if it's the Chromium console running ? I tried a `console.log("test")` but nothing happened.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. What console are you looking at? Are you looking at the console that opens when you call `window.openDevTools();` in your Electron app?

Comment: Nop i'm looking at my shell, after the `>electron` running lines. Just after typed `npm start`.

Comment: In that case I'm not exactly sure what's going on. I went ahead and created a simple Electron app myself to test and it worked fine. http://i.imgur.com/UUrRgqJ.gifv

Comment: Yep this works perfectly on Linux for me also, but not on Windows unfortunately...

Comment: Ohhhh, I missed that tidbit. There is a bug with the readline module on Windows. I know this because I tried to use `eslint --init` on my Windows box and the prompt was all screwed up, not accepting input. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5384#issuecomment-196507143